# .OnKey Macro linking

Tags: vba, macros

Here is my code. All the macros work when their respective key is pressed except the `Sorter`. Not sure why the `Handler` is not calling the macro when the key is pressed. Any ideas?

```
Public Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.OnKey "^%{~}", "DailyStatusSorter"
End Sub

Public Sub DailyStatusSorter()
' DailyStatusSorter Macro
' Sorts Daily Staus buy completed, priority , then date from oldest to newest.
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Daily_Status").Sort.SortFields _
    .Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Daily_Status").Sort.SortFields _
    .Add Key:=Range("Daily_Status[Last edited by]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnCellColor _
    , Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Daily_Status").Sort.SortFields _
    .Add Key:=Range("Daily_Status[Priority]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order _
    :=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Daily_Status").Sort.SortFields _
    .Add Key:=Range("Daily_Status[Date]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
    xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Daily_Status").Sort
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the exact key combination you are pressing to run it?

Comment: Alt + Ctrl + Enter

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `Ctrl + Alt + Enter` combination, remove the `{}` from the key:

```
Application.OnKey "^%~", "DailyStatusSorter"
```

If you keep `"^%{~}"`, you will need to press `Ctrl + Alt + Shift + ~`

p.s.: move the macro to an independent code Module, not in the workbook's code module

Comment: Unfortunately still no result on when the key is pressed

Comment: @Andrew did you try to use any other key combination with the same code for the same function? I mean try to narrow the problem by verifying if it is only due to the key combination, to the place you call it (in Workbook_open, etc..? (p.s: it worked perfectly for me)

Comment: @Andrew and by the way, try to move the macro to an independent code `Module`, not in the workbook's code module.